How to randomly sample a dataset with specific constraints on two boolean conditions by Python?
I'm working with a dataset of 2,500 samples, and I need to extract a random subset of 666 samples while meeting specific conditions based on two boolean columns.
The dataset (df) contains the following columns:

ID
cond_1 (boolean: True/False)
cond_2 (boolean: True/False)

When sampling the subset, I need to ensure these conditions are satisfied:

The number of True values in cond_1 should be exactly 181.
The number of True values in cond_2 should be exactly 181.
The number of False values in cond_1 should be exactly 485.
The number of False values in cond_2 should be exactly 485.
The total number of samples in the subset should be exactly 666.

Additionally:

Since this is a random sampling, the subset should not consist entirely of samples where both cond_1 and cond_2 are either both True or both False. There must be combination of True/False or False/True.

Is there a recommended way to achieve this type of constrained sampling in Python?
Any code examples or libraries that could help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': range(1, 2501),
    'cond_1': np.random.choice([True, False], size=2500),
    'cond_2': np.random.choice([True, False], size=2500)
})

# Create the groups based on conditions
group_cond1_true = df[df['cond_1'] == True]
group_cond1_false = df[df['cond_1'] == False]

group_cond2_true = df[df['cond_2'] == True]
group_cond2_false = df[df['cond_2'] == False]

# Sample from each group to meet constraints
sample_cond1_true = group_cond1_true.sample(n=181, random_state=42)
sample_cond1_false = group_cond1_false.sample(n=485, random_state=42)

sample_cond2_true = group_cond2_true.sample(n=181, random_state=42)
sample_cond2_false = group_cond2_false.sample(n=485, random_state=42)

# Combine the samples to create the final dataset
df_extracted = pd.concat([sample_cond1_true, sample_cond1_false, sample_cond2_true, sample_cond2_false]).drop_duplicates()

# Check if the conditions are met
print(f"Total length: {len(df_extracted)}")
print(f"cond_1 True count: {df_extracted['cond_1'].sum()}")
print(f"cond_2 True count: {df_extracted['cond_2'].sum()}")
print(f"cond_1 False count: {(~df_extracted['cond_1']).sum()}")
print(f"cond_2 False count: {(~df_extracted['cond_2']).sum()}")
print()
count = df_extracted.groupby(['cond_1', 'cond_2']).size()
print("Extracted counts:\n", count)

The code above generated df_extracted with the size of 1148, not 666.
Total length: 1148
cond_1 True count: 454
cond_2 True count: 460
cond_1 False count: 694
cond_2 False count: 688

Extracted counts:
 cond_1  cond_2
False   False     396
        True      298
True    False     292
        True      162
dtype: int64


Nowhere in your code are you attempting to address the intersection problem between the samplings... Once you sampled cond_1 == True, check how many of these also satisfy cond_2 == True before proceeding to sampling more of cond_2 = True and cond_1 == False to complete, and finally complete with the appropriate number of cond_1 = False and cond_2 == False...

@Julien
Thank you. I understand the problem, but since I couldn't figure out how to implement the logic in the code, I posted a shortened snippet.

Code
First, create a data frame with a randomized array of a set number of True and False, and give it a cumcount.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a True/False array
n_true, n_false = 181, 485
values = np.array([True] * n_true + [False] * n_false)

# Randomly permute the array twice to create two columns in the DataFrame
df_sample = pd.DataFrame({
    'cond_1': np.random.permutation(values),
    'cond_2': np.random.permutation(values)
})

# Add a cumcount column 'cc' in each group of 'cond_1' and 'cond_2'
df_sample['cc'] = df_sample.groupby(['cond_1', 'cond_2']).cumcount()

df_sample:
     cond_1  cond_2   cc
0      True   False    0
1      True   False    1
2     False   False    0
..      ...     ...  ...
663    True    True   50
664   False    True  128
665   False    True  129

[666 rows x 3 columns]


Second, randomize df and then give cumcount to extract the IDs that match df_sample.
target_id = df_sample.merge(
    df.assign(cc=df.sample(frac=1).groupby(['cond_1', 'cond_2']).cumcount()), 
    how='left')['ID']
out = df[df['ID'].isin(target_id)]

out
        ID  cond_1  cond_2
5        6    True    True
8        9   False    True
12      13   False   False
...    ...     ...     ...
2487  2488    True   False
2489  2490    True   False
2490  2491   False   False

[666 rows x 3 columns]

If you don't want the results to be sorted by ID, use out.sample(frac=1) instead of out.

Third, verify that the sample was extracted correctly.
print('number of rows :', len(out))
print('Number of True in all columns : \n', out[['cond_1', 'cond_2']].sum())

output:
number of rows : 666
Number of True in all columns : 
 cond_1    181
cond_2    181
dtype: int64

In this case, it should meet your desired result, but if it doesn't, run the code again from the beginning.

Thank you very much. It achieved my original goal perfectly. By the way, would this extraction method be considered constrained random sampling or stratified random sampling? I’d love to hear your thoughts if you have any insights on this. Thanks again!

It is not so hard to construct a way to randomly select samples that satisfy the constraints, but it is not always obvious what the distribution is. I assume you want to sample uniformly among all the possible ways that samples could be selected such that your constraints are satisfied. There may be simpler ways that sample uniformly (e.g. maybe the selected answer does; incan see an argument for that), but this was my attempt to construct an approach that does so.

First, the idea:
Let's label the samples with letters depending on the truth of the conditions:

(False, False): a
(False, True): b
(True, False): c
(True, True): d

Suppose there are na samples of type a, nb samples of type b, and so on.
One way of satisfying the constraints is if you pick 181 d's and 485 a's. There are special.binom(nd, 181) * special.binom(na, 485) ways to do this, where binom is the binomial coefficient (n choose k).
Another is if you pick 180 d's, 1 c, 1 b, and 484 a's. There are special.binom(nd, 180) * special.binom(nc, 1) * special.binom(nb, 1) * special.binom(na, 484) ways to do this.
And so on. The strategy will be to:

List the possible ways of satisfying the constraints (all a's and d's, 484 a's + 1 b + 1 c + 180 d's, and so on)
Count the number possibilities of each
Choose a way of satisfying the constraints from this distribution
Choose specific samples at random according to the chosen way of satisfying the constraints (i.e. randomly select 181 of the type d's and 485 of the type a's)


The last part is easy; here's code for the first three with comments to explain what is going on.
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng()
from scipy import special, stats

# Generate samples
# (You would just use your real samples)
x, y = rng.random((2, 2500)) > 0.5

# Count the number of each type of sample
na = np.sum((x == 0) & (y == 0))
nb = np.sum((x == 0) & (y == 1))
nc = np.sum((x == 1) & (y == 0))
nd = np.sum((x == 1) & (y == 1))

# The binomial coefficients themselves are too big to work with;
# they will overflow. 
# This calculates the log of binomial coefficients directly.
def log_binom(n, k):
    return -(np.log(n + 1) + special.betaln(k + 1, n - k + 1))

# # (sanity check that it works)
# n, k = rng.integers(100, 200), rng.integers(25, 75)
# np.testing.assert_allclose(log_binom(n, k), np.log(special.binom(n, k)))

# Calculate the logs of the numbers of possibilities for each way of
# satisfying the constraints
log_freq = []
for i in range(182):
    d = i
    c = 181 - i
    b = 181 - i
    a = 485 - i
    log_freq.append(log_binom(nd, d) + log_binom(nc, c) 
                    + log_binom(nb, b) + log_binom(na, a))

# Calculate the log of the total number of possibilities of satisfying the
# constraints  
total_log_freq = special.logsumexp(log_freq)

# This is equivalent to dividing all the counts by the total number,
# but in log-space
logpmf = log_freq - total_log_freq

# This is equivalent to calculating the cumulative distribution function,
# but in log-space
logcdf = np.logaddexp.accumulate(logpmf)

# Use inverse transform sampling to select the way of satisfying the constraints.
# This is not perfect because with floating point math there is exactly 0 probability of choosing some of the very improbable ways of satisfying the constraints.
# Ideally we would sample directly from the exp-uniform distribution (not the log-uniform distribution), but I expect that this is good enough in practice.
log_probability = np.log(rng.uniform())
i = np.searchsorted(logcdf, log_probability)

# Randomly select this many of each type of sample
a, b, c, d = 485 - i, 181 - i, 181 - i, i
a, b, c, d
# (420, 116, 116, 65)
# Randomly sample 420 type a samples, 116 type b and c samples, and 65 type d samples

